# In sympy, Is it possible to create a matrix symbol that is a function?

Tags: function, matrix, sympy

For a matrix, I want to write something like:

```
H_t = sp.MatrixSymbol('H',2,2)(t)
```

to show that the matrix is a function of t.

As a work around, I tried using a non-commutative function, then substituting a matrix later:

```
H_t = sp.Function('H', commutative=False)(t)
```

However, this incorrectly evaluates `H_t * H_t_1` to be a tensor (I believe it is the same issue as this stack overflow question [Substitute a Sympy matrix into a polynomial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445949/substitute-a-sympy-matrix-into-a-polynomial))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you change the name to represent this functionality:

```py
>>> H_t = sp.MatrixSymbol('H(t)',2,2)
H(t)
```

Or you can use non-commutative functions and replace them with matrix symbols when ready to treat them like matrices:

```py
>>> h=Function('H', commutative=False)(t)
>>> g=Function('G', commutative=False)(t)
>>> m={h:MatrixSymbol('Mh',2,2),g:MatrixSymbol('Mg',2,2)}
>>> type((h*g).subs(m,simultaneous=True))
sympy.matrices.expressions.matmul.MatMul
```

Comment: It seems putting the t in the name means that other sympy functions won't treat it as a function of t; for example, ``` integrate(H_t,t) ``` gives tH(t). Similarly, H_t.subs(t,t_1) returns H(t) unchanged. This is a good idea but not what I'm looking for.

Comment: The simultaneous=True flag was something I didn't know about, and what I was missing. Thanks again!